# How to handle returning PDF file to be able to display in browser

Tags: php, extjs, tcpdf

I have ExtJS application that is querying database and showing the results in grid which is working properly.

Users can select any record from the grid by checkbox then send to server to print out. The server side code generate PDF file ( by TCPDF ) and return result the browser, it also works properly.

My problem is, client side doesn't show PDF file in browser window, instead of view just showing binary form of the PDF page.

So, could you please help me, how can I handle returning PDF file to show client screen?

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
{
xtype: 'button',
width: 90,
text: 'GÖNDER',
cls: 'x-btn-gonder',
handler: function(){
    var ppt     = Ext.getCmp('labelType').getValue();
    var sb      = Ext.getCmp('basic-statusbar');
    var count   = Ext.getCmp('labelGrids').getSelectionModel().getCount();
    var rows    = Ext.getCmp('labelGrids').getSelectionModel().getSelection();

    if(ppt == null) {
        dialog.show();
    } else {
    if(count > 0) {
        var paper = {};
        paper.PAPER = ppt;

        var prints = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            prints[i] = {'LABEL_ID': rows[i].data.LABEL_ID, 'LABEL_TYPE':rows[i].data.LABEL_TYPE}
        }
        paper.LABELS = prints;

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'lib/labels/print_label.php',
            timeout: 60000,

            success: function() 
            { 
                Ext.Msg.alert('İşlem Başarılı', 'Etiketler yazıcıya gönderildi.');

                // set statusbar text after print
                sb.setStatus({
                    text: 'Etiketler yazıcıya gönderildi..!',
                    iconCls: 'x-status-saved',
                    clear: true
                });

                // remove checked items
                Ext.select('.x-grid-row-selected').each(function (element) {
                    Ext.getCmp('labelGrids').getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                });
            },
            failure: function() { Ext.Msg.alert('Yazdırma Hatası', 'Etiketler yazdırılamadı..!')},
            jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(paper)
        });

        // clear combobox selected value after send to printer
        Ext.getCmp('labelType').reset();

        // console.log(Ext.JSON.encode(prints));
    } else if(count == 0) {
        sb.setStatus({
            iconCls: 'x-status-error',
            text: 'Lütfen yazdırmak istediğiniz etiketleri seçiniz!'
        });
    }                           
    winPaper.hide();
    }
}
```

}

**SERVER SIDE**

```
<?php
require_once('../tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$db = new mysqli("10.10.10.10","blabla","blablabla","label");
$db->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$db->query("SET SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'");
$db->query("SET lc_time_names = 'tr_TR'");

$datas = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// get paper type from json array
$paper  = $datas->PAPER;

foreach($datas->LABELS as $data)
{
    $lblids[] = $data->LABEL_ID;
}

$ids = implode(",", $lblids);

// get labels from db
$sql = "SELECT LABEL_ID, SUBSYS_ART_NO, ARTICLE_DESC, END_DATE, PRODUCT_PRICE, SHELF_PRICE, LABEL_TEXT, LABEL_TYPE, LABEL_SIGN, PROMO FROM labels WHERE LABEL_ID IN (".$ids.")";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $labels[] = $row;
}

switch($paper)
{
    case "SF":
        print_shelf($labels);
    break;
}

function print_shelf($labels)
{
    # defining PDF variables
    $width      = 100;
    $height     = 55;
    $pageSize   = array($width, $height);

    # create new BMPL PDF price label
    $pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, $pageSize, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    # set PDF document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Oğuz Çelikdemir, Metro Systems Turkey');
    $pdf->SetTitle('BMPL Price Label');

    # disable pdf document header and footer
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    # set PDF default font
    $pdf->setDefaultMonospacedFont('PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED');

    # set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 2);

    $crs   = array('width' => 0.5);
    $style = array('width' => 0.25, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0));

    for($i = 0; $i < count($labels); $i++)
    {
        # add PDF page
        $pdf->addPage();

        # split the price values
        $prdPrice = explode(".", $labels[$i]['PRODUCT_PRICE']);
        $shfPrice = explode(".", $labels[$i]['SHELF_PRICE']);

        $prcLeft  = $prdPrice[0];
        $prcRight = $prdPrice[1];
        $shfLeft  = $shfPrice[0];
        $shfRight = $shfPrice[1];

        # Label variables
        $priceLeft      = '<span style="color:#b4b4b4;">'.$prcLeft.'</span>';
        $priceLeftCent  = '<span style="color:#b4b4b4;">'.$prcRight.'</span';
        $priceRight     = '<span style="color:#b4b4b4;">'.$shfLeft.'</span>';
        $priceRightCent = '<span style="color:#000;">'.$shfRight.'</span>';
        $taxLabelLeft   = '<span style="color:#b4b4b4;">KDV\'Lİ</span>';
        $taxLabelRight  = 'KDV\'Lİ';
        $articleDesc    = '\''.$labels[$i]['ARTICLE_DESC'].'\'';
        $articleNumber  = $labels[$i]['SUBSYS_ART_NO'];
        $labelText      = '\''.$labels[$i]['LABEL_TEXT'].'\'';
        $promoDate      = $labels[$i]['END_DATE'];
        $promoLabel     = $labels[$i]['PROMO'];

        ////////////// PREPARE THE LABELS \\\\\\\\\\\\\\

        # LABEL BOTTOM
        $pdf->SetFont('dinpro', '', 6);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(20, 0,  5, 50, $articleNumber, '', 1, 0, true, 'L');
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(20, 0, 28, 50, $promoDate, '', 1, 0, true, 'L');

        if(is_null($promoLabel)) {
            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(20, 0, 42, 50, '', '', 1, 0, true, 'R');
        } else {
            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(20, 0, 42, 50, 'FIRSAT', '', 1, 0, true, 'R');
        }

        # LABEL LEFT
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob', 'B', 10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(90, 20, $articleDesc, 0, 'L', false, 1, 5, 5.50);
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob', '', 8);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(45, 10, 5, 17, 'SATIŞ FİYATI', '', 1, 0, true, 'F');
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob', 'B', 44);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(30, 27, 5, 24, $priceLeft, '', 1, 0, true, 'R', true);
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob', 'B', 20);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(15, 10, 26.5, 28.5, $priceLeftCent, '', 1, 0, true, 'R', true);
        $pdf->SetFont('dinpro', '', 6);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(15, 10, 29.2, 37.3, $taxLabelLeft, '', 1, 0, 'L', true);

        if(!is_null($labels[$i]['LABEL_SIGN']))
        {
            $pdf->Line(7, 41, 38, 22, $crs);
        }

        # LABEL RIGHT
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob','',8);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(45, 10, 50, 17, $labelText, '', 1, 0, true, 'C');
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob', 'B', 58);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(45, 30, 42, 21, $priceRight, '', 1, 0, true, 'R', true);
        $pdf->SetFont('dinprob', 'B', 24);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(15, 10, 79.5, 28, $priceRightCent, '', 1, 0, true, 'R', true);
        $pdf->SetFont('dinpro', '', 6);
        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(15, 10, 81, 38.5, $taxLabelRight, '', 1, 0, 'L', true);

        $js .= 'print(true);';
        $pdf->IncludeJS($js);

        ob_end_clean();
        return $pdf->Output('bpml_label.pdf', 'I');
    }
}        
?>
```

[image: console output]

Comment: What content type is sent from server?   try set to application/pdf

Comment: @DanielMagnusson returning file type PDF

Comment: if you have the PDF in someplace where apache (or any other webserver) has access, you could return the URL and open it in a new window instead of returning the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried above suggestions but no success so that I did alternate way as belows :

First of all, some browsers doesn't support response object like PDF, therefore, I did postback to PDF file url then handle with an iframe inside the Ext window object.

```
success: function(response)
{
   var _url = response.responseText;

   new Ext.Window({
      title: 'Labels',
      id: 'pdfWindow',
      layout: 'fit',
      width: 600,
      height: 500,
      closeAction: 'destroy', // take notice that 'hide' action doesn't work
      items: [{
         xtype: 'component',
         autoEl: {
            tag: 'iframe', // we need iframes 'src' parameter to handle PDF
            style: 'height:100%; width:100%; border:none',
            // here we used special style to get rid of iframe title
            src: _url
         }
      }]
   }).show();
},
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
// we need an unique ID to be able set unique file name
$uniqeid = uniqid(); # if you want add true parameter to extend sensibility
$filename = '/var/www/label/print/'.$uniqeid.'.pdf';
# F parameter creating the file in specified directory, don't forget to set security 777 for folder ortherwise you might take an error
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
echo('/print/'.$uniqeid.'.pdf');
```

Answer (score 2):

When you return the the PDF to the client, send it with the correct content type. Add this header before sending back the response

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Then the client can properly decide, what to do with the document.

Comment: Dear Olaf, I tried but no success. One question, where we put this directive? Header of the script or just before the return value?

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir See modified answer, I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Add target `_blank` to the printing button. Your browser will open it in a new window with PDF content generated by server.

Add content header as others advise:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```